# JQuery Unslider not working on homepage

Tags: jquery, html, css, path, unslider

I'm trying to get the unslider plugin to work. Its not working, I've checked the path and it seems to be correct. Any ideas? I am following the steps on their site: http://unslider.com/

I am also not getting any errors in the console log hence I have no idea what I'm doing wrong? The script link is before the code so I don't understand the error.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Hello!</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <script src="js/JQuery.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" src="unslider-master/dist/css/unslider.css">
    <script src="js/unslider.js"></script> 
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='main_page_container'>
      <div class="my-slider">
        <ul>
          <li>My slikjmhhhhhhhhhkjjjjjjjjjjde</li>
          <li>Another slide</li>
          <li>My last slide</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <script>
        // Using the Unslider. Not working.
        $(document).ready(function() {
          $('.my-slider').unslider();
        });
        // Testing is JQUERY is working. Not working.
        $("#navbar").click(function() {
          $("#navbar").css("background-color", "yellow");
        });

        window.onload = function() {
          if (window.jQuery) {  
            // jQuery is loaded  
            alert("Yeah!");
          } else {
            // jQuery is not loaded
            alert("Doesn't Work");
          }
        }
      </script>
      <div class="box_one">
        <div class='headline'>
          <b><p id='headline_text'>An Eye-Catching Headline</p></b><br>
          <button id='textChanger'>Add text</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='shipping_info'><p class='shipping_text'><b>Free Shipping World Wide</b></p></div>
    <div class="box_two"><div id='side_bar'> side bar</div></div>
    <div class='about-panel'><label id='about-panel-text'>Why Us?</label> </div>
    <div class='divider-whitespace'></div>
    <footer id='footer'></footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Here is what I'm getting:**

[image]

Comment: its working fine here ,https://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/rwgo07sb/. only thing thats missing is `Unlisder-dots.css`,https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/unslider/2.0.3/css/unslider.css

Comment: I've added the unslider-dots.css. But the code is not working on my website. I have checked the JQuery, but the slides are not moving or seem to be styled.

Comment: well it will not autoplay you need to click next/prev or set `autoplay=true`

Comment: It doesn't do anything when I click; not clickable. I've added the autoplay=true... doesn't work either. See the screen capture in the question update please

Comment: This plugin is supported only from jquery 1.7.2 and further, i beleive your using older version.

Comment: I changed the versions to  jQuery v2.2.1. Still not working..

Comment: could you try using the same library versions used in jsfiddle in your script as well, probably you can just copy the libraries from external resources in jsfiddle and use it.